# Custom Cluster Marker Google Map AngularJS2

Tags: angularjs

Im migrating my Google Map from Java Script implementation to Angular JS 2, I want to implement custom Cluster Marker as shown in the below Link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Can any one share the document / reference code in Angular JS 2 to achieve the same. I couldnt find right document to implement it.